# Possible combination of data with constraints

Tags: vba, excel, combinations

I am working with planetary gear combination.
The value conditions is as below:

```
s: min(20), max(40)  
p: min(20), max(40)  
r: s + 2*p

constraint:  
(s + r)/4>0 : true  
p + 2 < (s + p)*sin(180/4) : true
```

I would like to calculate all the possible even number combinations of s, p, and r.
The example of output:

```
s       p      r  
20     30     80  
40     20     80  
.  
.
```

Can anyone help me?
I have been looking around but have not found solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might define two private boolean functions representing the constraints, here is an example of the first constraint:

```
Private Function constraint1(ByVal s As Integer, ByVal p As Integer, ByVal r As Integer) As Boolean
    If (s+r)/4 > 0 Then
        constraint1 = True
    Else
        constraint1 = True
    End If
End Function
```

Then, you could define a loop for all the numbers going from `20` to `40` both for `s` and `r` and verify if the three constraints are respected: if so, then you print the values on the sheet:

```
For s = 20 To 40
    For p = 20 To 40
        r = s + 2*p
        If constraint1(s,p,r) And constraint2(s,p,r) Then
            'it's a valid trio of (s,p,r), so you can print it on the sheet
        End If
    Next p 
Next s
```

P.s. I'm not sure to have understood the "all the even numbers", but if you really want `s` and `p` to be only even, then you can add the `Step` operator the `For` cycle in order to make it be always even:

```
For s = 20 To 40 Step 2
```

Like above, `s` will be `20`, then `22`, then `24` (it will basically step of 2 each loop).